# How do you do a nested for in a table in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an object that looks like this:

```
foo = {
    "key1": [{...}, {...}, ...],
    "key2": [{...}, {...}, ...],
    ....
}
```

Then in my Component html I want to do something like this:

```
<table>
    <!-- for each key in foo -->
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- for each obj in foo[key] -->
    <tr>
        <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- endfor -->
    <!-- endfor -->
</table>
```

My issue is that based on the examples provided in [Angular 2 website](http://angular.io) writing something like this

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="key in foo">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

would create many rows with the key in the object, but then I don't know how to append the second for. How can achieve this?

(If necessary I'm, willing to add more information)

Comment: Use Object.keys to get keys from data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Misko Hevery](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246), maps should not be used with `ngFor` because there is no ordering to the keys and hence the iteration is unpredictable. It was possible in Angular1, but is not supported in Angular2.

In Angular2, there is a plan to provide a `mapToIterable` pipe. However, as of Angular2 beta 9, the pipe is not yet available.

Luckily, to implement the `mapToIterable` pipe yourself is trivial:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'mapToIterable', pure: false })
export class MapToIterable implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {

        return Object.keys(value).sort().map(
          key => { return { "key": key, "value": value[key] }});
    }
}
```

You could then use the template syntax of `ngFor` to achieve the end result:

```
<table>
    <template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="foo | mapToIterable">
        <tr>
             <td>{{item.key}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="#value of item.value">
             <td>{{value.name}}</td>
        </tr> 
    </template>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are expecting. (I didn't test below code. but you could see how second for loop is used)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th *ngFor="#key of foo">
            {{ key }}
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="#key of foo">
       <tr *ngFor="#obj of foo[key]">
          <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Updated table

```
  <table>
        <tbody *ngFor="#key of foo">
           <tr><td>{{key}} </td></tr>
           <tr *ngFor="#obj of foo[key]">
              <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: No, this doesnt do what I want. This first adds the 5 rows of the keys and then the objects for each of the keys. What I want is to show the row of the key then all the objects in the key and repeat.

Comment: <th> will add columns not rows.

Comment: It doesnt help anyways.